# How to aggregate fields with different AND clause within RIGHT JOIN?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

```
SELECT
    externalsource.id,
    externalsource.url,
    externalsource.last_fetch,
    SUM(scripttracking.records) AS jobs_per_week
FROM
    scripttracking
RIGHT JOIN
    externalsource
ON
    externalsource.script_name = scripttracking.script_name
AND
    scripttracking.created_on > %s
GROUP BY
    externalsource.id
```

Any idea how can I modify this query so that it will aggregate scripttracking.records with different "AND" condition?

Essentially, what I need to get is:

```
SUM(scripttracking.records) for scripttracking.created_on > now() - 1 week

SUM(scripttracking.records) for scripttracking.created_on > now() - 1 month

SUM(scripttracking.records) for scripttracking.created_on > now() - 1 year
```

All these fields I need to include in 1 result queryset.

Something like:

```
ID, URL, LAST_FETCH, JOBS_PER_WEEK, JOBS_PER_MONTH, JOBS_PER_YEAR
1, http://google.ru, 25/01/2016, 7, 23, 8889
```

Comment: use a case statement in your sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally we'd use `CASE` statement but Postgres offers us more comfortable solution so better to use [FILTER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html)

```
SELECT
    externalsource.id
    ,externalsource.url
    ,externalsource.last_fetch
    ,SUM(scripttracking.records) AS jobs_per_week
    ,SUM(scripttracking.records) FILTER (WHERE scripttracking.created_on > now() - 1 week)
    ,SUM(scripttracking.records) FILTER (WHERE scripttracking.created_on > now() - 1 month)
    ,SUM(scripttracking.records) FILTER (WHERE scripttracking.created_on > now() - 1 year)
FROM
    scripttracking
RIGHT JOIN
    externalsource
ON
    externalsource.script_name = scripttracking.script_name
AND
    scripttracking.created_on > %s
GROUP BY
    externalsource.id
```

Comment: Learn something new every day.  Filters on aggregates... who knew!   Though I think the column names on these 3 new columns could be a big much :P  I appreciate humor and the removal of the 21st century jab as well :P

Comment: @xQbert Yeah, I didn't feel like naming them, I'm sure the final user will do that in his free time. In the mean while may I recomend [this blog note](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2015-02/modern-sql)? It goes over some new goodies like `FILTER`.

Comment: Note here: it was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.4

Answer (score 3):

Using a case statement to evaluate the values to sum otherwise use a 0.

Note this is inclusive logic so sum of month contains sum of week, and sum of year contains some of week and month.

```
SELECT
    externalsource.id,
    externalsource.url,
    externalsource.last_fetch,
    SUM(case when scripttracking.created_on > now() - 1 week then scripttracking.records else 0 end) AS jobs_per_week,
    SUM(case when scripttracking.created_on > now() - 1 month then scripttracking.records else 0 end) AS jobs_per_Month,
    SUM(case wehn scripttracking.created_on > now() - 1 year then scripttracking.records else 0 end) AS jobs_per_Year
FROM
    scripttracking
RIGHT JOIN
    externalsource
ON
    externalsource.script_name = scripttracking.script_name
AND
    scripttracking.created_on > %s
GROUP BY
    externalsource.id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use case statements to get the aggregates for the different columns. 
In short, this can be written as:

```
SELECT
    externalsource.id,
    externalsource.url,
    externalsource.last_fetch,
    SUM(scripttracking.records) for scripttracking.created_on > now() [JOBS_PER_WEEK], 
SUM(scripttracking.records) for scripttracking.created_on > now() [JOBS_PER_MONTH],
SUM(scripttracking.records) for scripttracking.created_on > now() [JOBS_PER_YEAR]
from 
..... your rest of your query goes here.
```

Comment: Postgresql doesn't allow identifier delimiting with square brackets.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know that. As such, The question wasn't specifically for Postgres, or I might have missed it in case it was mentioned. Also, my intent was just to demonstrate how the solution would look like using "case".

Comment: The question has a `postgresql` tag and if you want an agnostic delimiting use double brackets (and upper case identifier is a bad idea).